# Invalid argument(s): Invalid locale "en"

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

I have an application supporting Three languages (English, Arabic, and Kurdish). whenever I change the application's selected language there is no problem with any language, but when I change it to Kurdish and then `restart app`, navigating to certain screen causes the following error.

```
Invalid argument(s): Invalid locale "en"
```

I don't know what restarting an app does with the Locales, but it causes me this problem where the application completely stops working.

My Delegate List:

```
final delegatesList = [
      GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      KuMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      KuWidgetLocalizations.delegate,
      MaterialLocalizationKuDelegate(),
      ...context.localizationDelegates,
    ];
```

My Supported Locales:

```
startLocale: const Locale("en"),
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale("en"),
        Locale("ku"),
        Locale("ar"),
      ],
```

Answer (score 1):

try to replace by "en_US"